# Que uso para que en JS mi condicional verifique si un valor de un objeto (Input text en html) tiene o no tiene texto escrito en la casilla?

Tags: javascript

Soy nuevo en StackOverflow, Front End y en la programación en general. un gusto. tengo la duda del titulo.

Tengo hecho un formulario. lo que quiero es que al llenar datos en los inputs correspondientes y dar click al botón, javascript detecte si hay o no hay strings en las casillas para que después envíe a la consola los datos. si hay datos, que los muestre en consola y si no, que muestre otro mensaje.
adjunto codigo que hice hasta el momento. Gracias.

```
const nombreYa = document.getElementById("nombre_apellido")
const mail = document.getElementById("correo_electronico")
const pass = document.getElementById("contraseña")
const again_pass = document.getElementById("repite_contraseña")
const register = document.getElementById("btn")

const nombre = nombreYa.value
const email = mail.value
const passw = pass.value

let user = {
    nombre,
    email,
    passw
}

function guardar_datos(){ 
    const usuario = user

    if ((user.nombre = String) && (user.email = String) && (user.passw = String)){
        console.log("El usuario es: " + usuario)
    } else {
        console.log("No hay datos")
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const again_pass = document.getElementById("repite_contraseña")
const register = document.getElementById("btn")
//Es mejor obtener el valor del input directament asi te ahorras declarar otra variable
const nombreInput = document.getElementById("nombre_apellido").value
const emailInput = document.getElementById("correo_electronico").value
const passInput = document.getElementById("contraseña").value

let user = {
    nombre:nombreInput,
    email:emailInput,
    passw:passInput
}


function guardar_datos(user){
    //Se compara las variables obtenidas de los input con string vacios.
    if ((user.nombre !== "") && (user.email !== "") && (user.passw !== "")){
    //No hay empty string
        console.log(`El usuario es: ${user.nombre}`)
    } else {
    //Falta algun dato
        console.log("Hay string vacios")
    }


}
//No olvides llamar la funcion
guardar_datos(user)
```

De esta forma se puede realizar lo que estas preguntando, sin embargo hay una propiedad de los inputs que te permite validar que el contenido del input no se envie vacio es la propiedad `required` de HTML5

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" 
       id="example" onkeydown="example(this)" 
       placeholder="example" required/>
```

Como puedes ver al ponerle `required` al input, al oprimir el boton `submit` del formulario se cancelara el evento submit si es que el campo no tiene contenido, esto permite validar mas facilmente, o agregar una capa de validacion en tus web, espero haberte ayudado

Fuente :[Required HTML5](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias crack

Comment: @RodrigoDominguez un gusto ayduar, si te sirvio mi respuesta puedes marcarla como aceptada para asi cerrar tu pregunta.